# Why the history in gcb is not able to sort by branchname?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-build, google-cloud-repository

I'm able to sort by source but, unable to sort by branch, it shows only few branches for all sources.

I used it like
`Source:[source_name] OR Branch:[branch_name]`
in the history tab.

[image: Console]

can anyone tell me how to sort based on the branch?

Comment: even tried without OR, but works only for master branch

Comment: Where do you want to do this? on the console?

Comment: yes, on the console

Comment: Do you have other values than "Master" in your history when you scroll it? normally, the query builder propose you all the possible values. Type branch, select the key words, and all the possible values are proposed.

Comment: yes, many branches are there. but it doesn't show all branches.

Comment: And in suggestion, Its shows only a few branches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that is normal, I have the same thing on my side.

My history:
[image]

2 branches: Master and Open-source. However when I filter on the branch, even master I have nothing:

[image]

Why?? Because I have any trigger on the master or open-source branch. My trigger is on any branch.

[image]

Thus the build branch param is not set and thus you can search/filter on it. On others project, when I have a filter per branch, the history is correct and I can filter on the branch name.

An alternative is to use the gcloud command and the filter param like this

```
gcloud builds list --filter="substitutions.BRANCH_NAME=<YourBranchName>"
```

More detail on the [filter capabilities and expression](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/topic/filters)